# Killing a process leaves zombie process to haunt me... :(

Tags: c++, zombie-process

I have a program wherein i use fork. In the child process, i just login to a remote server and executes a command. In the parent process, i wait for the child to finish its task. If it doesnot finish it in a predetermined amount of time, i kill the child process using kill(child_pid, SIGTERM).
But i have noticed that this leaves behind zombie process like

```
93113 s000  Z+ 0:00.00 (ssh)
```

and as the timeouts increase, the zombie process also increase and ultimately the ssh cannot be used anymore.

how can i kill the child process without creating zombies that haunt me??

Comment: Zombies can't haunt. They are not ghosts. Zombies wander around.

Comment: When you say the parent "waits", do you mean that you literally use the `wait` sys-call?

Comment: i use the wait call.. but not after i kill the child.. that was the problem.. Hasturkun was right..

Comment: Frankly, if you kill children you deserve the zombies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you `kill` the child, you still need to `wait` for it.

Answer (score 1):

You must listen for `SIGCHLD` in the parent process and get the exit code of the child using `wait()` et al.